# Bootstrap 4 - why is text encroaching padding? How do I stop that?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple bs4 layout.  My left-menu is `<div class="col-md-2">` and my center-main-content is `<div class="col-md-6">` and my right-menu is `<div class="col-md-4">`.  Here is a view of the layout via Chrome dev-tool.  Green is padding and blue is content.  You can see that there is a nice space between the lef-menu and the center-main-content, however, there is no space between center-main-content and the right-menu.
[image: mainview]

Upon further review, I found that actually text is encroaching into the padding.  Please see text encroaching into the padding (green) below;

[image: text encroaching]

... and I looked even further and even found this text encroaching into padding;

How do I stop this?  I would like to have padding or margin between the columns.  Here is a quick snapshot of my markup

Here is the minimal code;

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>New Post!Admin Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
  <main role="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
         
            <!-- left menu -->
            <div class="col-md-2">

                <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    
                    <!-- content // collapseOne-->
                    <div class="card cardmargin">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                            <span class="fas fa-cloud"></span>Content</a>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Articles</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-newspaper"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">News</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-paper-plane"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Newsletters</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-comments"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Comments</a>
                                            <span class="badge badge-dark">42</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  

                </div>
  
            
            </div>
    
            <!-- center-main-content -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>Some Title</h2>
                </div>
                                    
                <div class="row">  
                    Some Category
                </div>
                                
                <div class="row">
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be 
                    distracted by the readable content of a page when looking 
                    at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it 
                    has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
                    opposed to using &#39;Content here, content here&#39;, 
                    making it look like readable English. Many desktop 
                    publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem 
                    Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for &#39;
                    lorem ipsum&#39; will uncover many web sites still in their 
                    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
                    sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected 
                    humour and the like).</p>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be 
                    distracted by the readable content of a page when looking 
                    at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it 
                    has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
                    opposed to using &#39;Content here, content here&#39;, 
                    making it look like readable English. Many desktop 
                    publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem 
                    Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for &#39;
                    lorem ipsum&#39; will uncover many web sites still in their 
                    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
                    sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected 
                    humour and the like).</p>
                </div>
                
            
            </div>  
            
            <!-- right-menu -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                
                </br>
                
                <!-- created -->
                <div class="row">
                    <h5>Created:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    2021-06-12 06:26:23            
                </div>
                    
                </br>
                
                <!-- updated -->
                <div class="row">
                    <h5>Updated:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    2021-06-12 06:26:23            
                </div>
                
                </br>
                
                <!-- Author -->
                <div class="row">
                    <h5>Author:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    mainuser            
                </div>
                
                </br>
                
                <!-- publised -->
                <div class="row">
                    <h5>Published?</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    No            
                </div>
                
                </br>
                 
                <!-- featured image --> 
                <div class="row">
                    <h5>Featured Image</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="https://development.example.com/filemanager_files/thumbs/no-image.jpg" >
                </div>
                
            
            </div>
            
       </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->  
    <hr>
</main>

<footer class="container">
  <p>&copy; example.com 1999-2021 || Phone:  +81-555-5555-5555      || Fax:  +81-555-5555-5555|| Email:  info@example.com      </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question.  External links can disappear making the question incomplete and impossible to answer. Adding only an image of code is not helpful [Read Why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: You should add minimal reproducible code, so that everyone can understand it properly. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: You should put your code in text on the question box. I recommend you o review [ask]

Comment: I included an external link to the actual minimal code.  The image was a further minimalist view of the code (grouped in html blocks to help understand the view).   I have since removed the image of html and the link to html.  I have added the html to the question.  I understand the request to modify the question but why would you vote to close the question?  Why vote to close?  Why not try and help which is the spirit of this board?  @Jean Gotop I have reviewed your question on how to read a json file - same thing - image in the question and you don't even mention what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your content in row without columns, but you don’t need the rows.

With Bootstrap, it’s generally a container, then a row, then a column, and then your content.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section role="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- left menu -->
            <div class="col-md-2">

                <div id="accordion" class="accordion">

                    <!-- content // collapseOne-->
                    <div class="card cardmargin">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                <span class="fas fa-cloud"></span>Content</a>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Articles</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-newspaper"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">News</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-paper-plane"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Newsletters</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-comments"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Comments</a>
                                            <span class="badge badge-dark">42</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>


            </div>

            <!-- center-main-content -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Some Title</h2> Some Category <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be
                    distracted by the readable content of a page when looking
                    at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it
                    has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as
                    opposed to using &#39;Content here, content here&#39;,
                    making it look like readable English. Many desktop
                    publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem
                    Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for &#39;
                    lorem ipsum&#39; will uncover many web sites still in their
                    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years,
                    sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected
                    humour and the like).</p>
                <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be
                    distracted by the readable content of a page when looking
                    at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it
                    has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as
                    opposed to using &#39;Content here, content here&#39;,
                    making it look like readable English. Many desktop
                    publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem
                    Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for &#39;
                    lorem ipsum&#39; will uncover many web sites still in their
                    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years,
                    sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected
                    humour and the like).</p>
            </div>

            <!-- right-menu -->
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <!-- created -->
                <h5>Created:</h5>
                <p>2021-06-12 06:26:23</p>

                <!-- updated -->
                <h5>Updated:</h5>
                <p>2021-06-12 06:26:23</p>

                <!-- Author -->
                <h5>Author:</h5>
                <p>mainuser</p>

                <!-- publised -->
                <h5>Published?</h5>
                <p>No</p>

                <!-- featured image -->
                <h5>Featured Image</h5>
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="Placeholder" src="https://via.placeholder.com/360x240.png">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <hr>
</section>

<footer class="container">
    <p>&copy; example.com 1999-2021 || Phone: +81-555-5555-5555 || Fax: +81-555-5555-5555|| Email: info@example.com </p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is add margin to the rows inside the right side, `<div class="row ml-2">`. The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>New Post!Admin Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
  <main role="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
         
            <!-- left menu -->
            <div class="col-md-2">

                <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    
                    <!-- content // collapseOne-->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                            <span class="fas fa-cloud"></span>Content</a>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Articles</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-newspaper"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">News</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-paper-plane"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Newsletters</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-comments"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Comments</a>
                                            <span class="badge badge-dark">42</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  

                </div>
  
            
            </div>
    
            <!-- center-main-content -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                
                <div class="row">
                    <h2>Some Title</h2>
                </div>
                                    
                <div class="row">  
                    Some Category
                </div>
                                
                <div class="row">
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be 
                    distracted by the readable content of a page when looking 
                    at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it 
                    has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
                    opposed to using &#39;Content here, content here&#39;, 
                    making it look like readable English. Many desktop 
                    publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem 
                    Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for &#39;
                    lorem ipsum&#39; will uncover many web sites still in their 
                    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
                    sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected 
                    humour and the like).</p>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be 
                    distracted by the readable content of a page when looking 
                    at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it 
                    has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
                    opposed to using &#39;Content here, content here&#39;, 
                    making it look like readable English. Many desktop 
                    publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem 
                    Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for &#39;
                    lorem ipsum&#39; will uncover many web sites still in their 
                    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
                    sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected 
                    humour and the like).</p>
                </div>
                
            
            </div>  
            
            <!-- right-menu -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                
    
                
                <!-- created -->
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    <h5>Created:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    2021-06-12 06:26:23            
                </div>
         
                
                <!-- updated -->
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    <h5>Updated:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    2021-06-12 06:26:23            
                </div>
                
                
                <!-- Author -->
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    <h5>Author:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    mainuser            
                </div>
                
                
                <!-- publised -->
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    <h5>Published?</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    No            
                </div>
                
                 
                <!-- featured image --> 
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    <h5>Featured Image</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    <img src="https://development.example.com/filemanager_files/thumbs/no-image.jpg" >
                </div>
                
            
            </div>
            
       </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->  
    <hr>
</main>

<footer class="container">
  <p>&copy; example.com 1999-2021 || Phone:  +81-555-5555-5555      || Fax:  +81-555-5555-5555|| Email:  info@example.com      </p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But there is already padding.  Why doesn't bs4 follow the padding that is already inserted by default?  When I remove <div class="row"> </div> from the center-main-content section, then the padding is honored.  Why is this please?

Comment: I am researching for give you an answer.